# Why the parent is not selected here?

Tags: jquery

Here I am writing code for a#x in jquery and I want to select div#answer but I cant.

```
<div id="answer" style="float: right">
    <a id="x" class="@answer.UserId" style="cursor:pointer;">
    </a>
</div>
```

And in the .js file:

```
$("#x").live("click", function () {
    alert($(this).parent("#answer").attr("id"));
})
```

Even this is not working too:

```
$("#x").live("click", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

I dont understand whats the problem?!:-|

Comment: `$("#x").live`, `.live()` is deprecated, try `.on()` or `.click()`

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.live()`, to complete Andy's comment.

Comment: Its not solved with $("#x").click too.

Comment: Even with .on() its not working.

Comment: Since you are using ids, and ids should be unique, you should only need `$("#answer")`. If you have more than one div with the id `answer`, then you need to fix that first (hint: use a class instead).

Comment: Its quite funny to check for a parent() with specific id for returning his attribute id, isn't it? Hope its for test purpose

Comment: @roasted No its not for test at all because I am a crazy man that know the id of an element but love to look for it.:))

Comment: sorry for the unless comment by lol @HamidReza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .**live**() method is deprecated use .**on**() like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#x").on("click", function () {
       alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtA8m/)

Comment: How could i check it without knowing OP code? Live() was for using delegation, used for dynamic elements added after DOM ready

Comment: This is the reason of using delegation, for elements added after handler declaration. OP was using live() so i think it was for dynamic elements. Hope it makes sense

Comment: He didnt asked delegation or something....just asked the parent that y I have given this ans...ok @roasted i learned something

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#x", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert( $(this).closest("#answer").prop("id") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As andy said live() is deprecated use .on().

```
$("#x").on("click", function () {
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/VyEJ3/

Comment: No delegation is used here